# how to get information of files under current directory in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ftp

I am implementing a FTP server in Linux. I use chroot commmand to change the currenty working directory when users send CWD command. But then I cannot use "ls -l" command to get file list information any more. 
Is there any way to get file information in this situation?

Comment: Use [dirent.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chroot` is not meant to change the current directory. You should use `chdir` for that.

(`chroot` changes the root filesystem. Therefore, after a `chroot` to a user directory, it is most likely that you cannot find `/bin/ls` anymore in this new root filesystem.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use chdir instead of chroot to change directories. You can then use [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) to scan the directory for children. Do not forget to call closedir as well.